# How to fix module exports not defined in javascript

Tags: exports-loader

```
module.exports = {
        LogValue1: function (data)
        {
            return somevalue;
        },
};

var fetch = require('./static/fetchData'); 
fetch.LogValue1(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is the require part, you need to you requireJs for that.

Just add to your page.

http://requirejs.org/

Comment: Old answer with no upvotes, but it solved my problem after half an hour of googling and trying other things. Thank you for posting.